# Recommendation for a download accelerator for Chromium

Tags: software-recommendation, firefox, chromium, extension

Firefox is very heavy, so I want to use Chromium but it doesn't have a download accelerator (multisegmented) like Firefox's DownThemAll! What can I do?

Comment: use a third party download accelerator...DAP or IDM...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install [JDownloader](http://jdownloader.org/) and use [this extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/laeghehalempfenbefbjbhccjcoakpmm) for chromium to integrate links with JD. JDownloader is a powerful download manager.